# Is there an easy way to break out on an if statement, like for or while loop?

Tags: java

I want to be able to break out of an if statement (A) if c() is true.

I sketched some code here, which would do what I want, however with a very ugly loop.
Is there any way I can do the equivalant, as fast as possible without a loop? Requirements:

1. c() should only be called if a() and b() are true. They should all be called once.
2. Without writing or reading an external variable.

```
    //statement A
    if (a()) {
            //always repeats once, dirty solution.
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                if (b()) {
                    if (c()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        //code
                    }
                }
                //code (if b() and c() are true, then this should be unreachable.)
            }
        }
```

I am going to repeat this code about 1000 times a second, for hours. So it that is the reason behind the performance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some kind of diagram which code should be executed based on the values of `a()`, `b()` and `c()`. You might want to add some kind of "truth table" to make it clear what you want.

Comment: I assume both `b` and `c` depend somehow on the iteration state. Right? Another question: Why such a weird loop that iterates just once?

Comment: @LittleSanti that's because I wanted to use the loop as a way to use the `break;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An if statement can be labelled (as can all statements). You can then use a labelled break to jump to after the if:

```
someLabel: if (condition) {
   // ...
   break someLabel;
   // ...
}
// It will continue from here.
```

However, this is not a very standard thing to do: consider restructuring your code so you can avoid having to use this.

Comment: That's lovely! I might as well add that if you break out of the if statement with an else, the else part won't be triggered.

Comment: @ope no, it's not lovely, it merely answers your direct question. As I say, this is not a widely-known language feature, as there is almost always a way to write it without (e.g. by reordering your conditions or extracting a method).

Comment: You might want to add another `// ...` after the `break someLabel;` to make it clear that it's going to skip the rest of the code in the `if` block.  As it is now, the `break` is kinda a no-op.

Comment: @Andy Turner, I don't agree. More knowledge is always better.

Comment: Having knowledge may be better, but in this case, you now have knowledge of a previously unknown (to you) code smell.  Code smells aren't usually seen as "lovely".

Answer (score 2):

I'd extract this logic and use `return` which works as `break` for a method, depending on  what you want and what the signature of the function is, you want to use `return` alone, or with `null` or `Optional.empty()` or even something else

```java
public void method() {
    if (a() && b() && c()) {
        return;
    }
    // unreachable if any of a(), b() or c() are false
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea! Might as well be good on the spaghetti code aspect

Answer (score 1):

try rewriting the inner condition in the way: *b and (not c)*